# Canon i-sensys MF744cdw - Running without colour toner

Tags: printer, toner

I bought the MF744cdw about 2 years ago. Since then the color toner has run out but a very small quantity is still there which is never enough to give a good printout.

Whenever I turn the printer on, it says that the toners have run out so need to be replaced. If I take the toner cartridges out then it says that cartridges are missing please insert them. Sometime by mistake the print settings on the computer end are left at colour print and then the printer gives a terrible color printout. All of this is very annoying.

Is there a way to permanently disable colour printing such that the priner never asks for new colour toner catridges since the current ones have run out, and the computer always always always gives black-white print command unless state otherwise i.e default for all applications is black and white.

I really want to know how I can disable the printer bothering with colour toner and cartridge level and colour printing option since I won't be buying the expensive toner cartridges for quite some time.

Comment: In Windows, setting the printer defaults will allow you to put it to black-and-white by default, and allow you to override it by going to the printer settings during a print.

Comment: What happens if you preset to "B&W only printing" ?

Comment: Here is the bad news, printers are known to use a tiny bit of (black or color), even while printing in color and/pr “black and white”.  The solution to your problem is to replace the toner

Comment: but I only want the black toner to be used always. If I remove the color toners, then the printers does not print at all and says there are no color cartridges. It won't even do black and white printing. If I put them back in, it says that the toner has run out, put new cartridges. How do I tell the printer to stop showing this message? By the way, I have set the print preferences to black and white in Windows.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried:
**Menu -> Function Settings -> Printer -> Printer Settings**
and force in **Black & White**?

Comment: I got rid of the printer